# Setting DataSource to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I'm trying to set DataSource to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn of my DataGridView. First I'm trying to bind a data source to my DataGridView, where bindingList is a List of my custom class Plugin with properties Name (string), Id (string) and Dependencies (List):

```
var bindingList = PluginsHandler.GetPlugins();
var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);


pluginsDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
pluginsDataGridView.DataSource = source;

pluginsDataGridView.Columns["pluginName"].DataPropertyName = "Name";
pluginsDataGridView.Columns["pluginID"].DataPropertyName = "Id";
```

So I can set my first two columns, but now I want to bind data to a third column of type DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. I try to do it on DataBindingComplete event:

```
private void pluginsDataGridView_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pluginsDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var comboCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell) pluginsDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["pluginDependencies"];
        var entry = pluginsDataGridView.Rows[i].DataBoundItem as IPlugin;
        comboCell.DataSource = entry.Dependencies;    
    }

}
```

Sadly comboBox is empty. Funny thing happens when I incorrectly put these lines after the first block of code I posted:

```
  var dependenciesColumn = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn) pluginsDataGridView.Columns["pluginDependencies"];
  dependenciesColumn.DataPropertyName = "Dependencies";
```

Then binding seem to start to work, as I can see that there are some entries in comboboxes, but when I try to hover mouse on combobox, I am getting an error that says DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid).

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning each `ComboCell` a data Source, set the `DataSource` of the column. I assume the Dependencies property of PlugIn class is a `List<string>`.

```
pluginsDataGridView.Columns["pluginDependencies"].DataSource = //list of dependencies
```

You have to set the `DataPropertyName` of the Dependencies ComboBoxColumn to get the initial values. If you don't set it you won't see any value in the column when the application is loaded.

```
pluginsDataGridView.Columns["pluginDependencies"].DataPropertyName = "Dependencies"
```

Edit:

You have a list of dependencies for a plug-in. i.e, more than one value. Usually, to select one value from list of values, you associate list with `ComboBoxColumn`. Achieving your requirement of multiple values from a list using standard `ComboBoxColumn` is difficult. Write a custom `CheckedComboBoxColumn` where you can display and select multiple values.

Comment: Yes, Dependencies property of Plugin class is a `List<string>`. The problem is that I would like to have different list of dependencies in each row, this is why I am trying to assign each `ComboCell` a data source. 
Anyway, even if I try to do it the way you presented, for example:
`var dependenciesColumn = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn) pluginsDataGridView.Columns["pluginDependencies"];
dependenciesColumn.DataSource = new string[] { "test1", "test2" };
dependenciesColumn.DataPropertyName = "Dependencies";`
the problem is still the same and with this code I am getting the same error.

Comment: I think I get your problem. See my edit in the answer.